# how to set for everyone all permissed in shared folder

Tags: c#

This is my code to set access rules for folder -

```
 FileSystemSecurity fs = File.GetAccessControl(FilePath); 
 fs.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("everyone",  
            FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow)); 
 File.SetAccessControl(FilePath, fs);
```

"Everyone" gets only read Permission

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if folder is share and set to folder access rules - everyone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194428/check-if-folder-is-share-and-set-to-folder-access-rules-everyone)

Comment: How do you know only read permissions are granted?

Answer (score 4):

Why are you `Deny`ing permissions if you want to give permissions? If I understand your question you wants to give full control to everyone? If so the following should work:

```
FileSecurity fSec = File.GetAccessControl(file);
fSec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
File.SetAccessControl(file, fSec);
```

Edit: Or did you mean that you wanted to make sure that everyone only ever could have read permissions? If so, you'd need to do it the other way around, allow `Read` and deny other permissions.

Comment: oop, this is my mistake.
my code is:
  FileSystemSecurity fs = File.GetAccessControl(FilePath);
        fs.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone",FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
        File.SetAccessControl(FilePath, fs);

Comment: @Sari-heksher: That looks like the same code snippet as I posted in my answer, so that worked for me. So if you check the permissions on the file afterwards for the Everyone group, it only has read permissions? Remember that you can't try it by trying to edit a file or something like that since there might be other permissions that deny editing rights, a deny always override an allow.